# jquery ajax get request adds query parameter _=1511454851

Tags: jquery

I have a website where all jquery requests were POST but have just changed those of them who doesn't sent any post variables to get..

But now jquery appends all get requests with a unix timestamp like this?

```
?_=1511454851
```

Below the correct url is printed to the console.. but the actual requested url is appended with the unix timestamp

```
console.log(a.url)
$.ajax(a).done(ajax_complete).fail(ajax_complete);
```

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of jQuery?

Comment: Posing your ajax code may be helpful.

Comment: You've stated something is happening, What do you want to do/know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the datestamp that gets added to the URL to prevent the response from the requests being cached.

If you don't want this, set `cache: true` in the AJAX request setup, but be aware that this may affect data integrity on the client.

Comment: See also the `cache` setting in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. It explains this behaviour